# Can' t do ClickOnce Deployment properly

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to deploy(ClickOnce Deployment) my web application which is developed in visual studio 2008.

But i'm not seeing the options correctly when i try to deploy, options are disabled when i opened properties tab.

i have refereed the below url.

http://www.edumax.com/c-sharp-basics-clickonce-deployment.html

but nothing seems working.

can anyone help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a web application? As in a website? You can't deploy those with ClickOnce. ClickOnce is only for WinForms or WPF based applications. To deploy a webapp, you need to publish it to a server. Right clicking the project in Solution Explorer and picking "Publish..." will get you started on that (although it can be a complex process)